# OpenSSL warning in 18.10 when decrypting something encrypted with 18.04

Tags: encryption, openssl

In 18.04 I encrypt files like so:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in somefile.tar.gz -out somefile.tar.gz.enc
```

I then decrypt using:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in somefile.tar.gz.enc -out somefile.tar.gz
```

I just upgraded one of machines to 18.10. When I decrypt a file in 18.10 that was encrypted in 18.04 (using the above method), I now get the following warning:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in somefile.tar.gz.enc -out somefile.tar.gz
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password:
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
```

I'm planning on using both 18.04 and 18.10, and will be transferring encrypted files between the two regularly. I know the above is only a *warning*, I'd just like to know what it means, and if it's possible to either suppress it or get rid of it completely (perhaps by encrypting differently on 18.04, or decrypting on 18.10 using some flags/params).

Comment: See the line below it?!

Comment: Have tried both of those params for encryption and decryption. Looks like they may not be available in 18.04, and from what little information I could find, they may also break backwards compatibility.